# Issue motorcycle start with Arduino

Tags: microcontroller

I have some issues when I start my motrocycle with my Arduino.

When I start my motorcycle, the Arduino loses power or something, but the logs show me that it restarts.

I don't really know why and how to stop it. It's a really simple setup and even if I only just use power to the Arduino and skip P1 and P2 and then start the motorcycle manually the Arduino restarts.

How is it possible to prevent this from happening in this circuit?

If I try a external power supply it works fine, of course.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Are you driving a relay coil directly from a GPIO as shown in your schematic? If so, (1) What is the required relay current? (2) What is the maximum GPIO current (and what voltage will it fall to at that current)? (3) Where is the relay coil snubber diode?

Comment: As I wrote in the description. Even if I disconnect P1 and P2 and only use 5v and GND to the Arduino, it restarts when I start the motorbike.

Comment: Can you measure what happens to the 5V power supply while cranking?

Comment: In nearly all cases the starting process pulls the 12V output from the battery to a much lower value.  It's likely falling below the input required by the 5V regulator feeding your USB.

Comment: jwh20 - yes. I beleve so also. But is there any way I can prevent that? I have tried to put in a few Capasitors, but that dont make any difference at all.

Comment: Is the `12V`, source, the battery of the motor cycle? Where are you putting the capacitors? 12 V side or 5V side?

Comment: yes that is the MC battery. I put them on the 5v side.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, relay beginner FAQ #1: use a freewheel diode across the relay coil or you might damage whatever you are driving it with.

It is also very common to get a big voltage surge when you turn on the ignition on vehicles, particularly 12V ones, because of starter motors etc. If you know what you are doing, you can try to hook up a big aluminium electrolyte bulk cap before your voltage regulator, some 500uF or larger.

It could also be transients or EMI causing the hobbyist electronics to become erratic. At a minimum you should add a 18V TVS or so at the input, but the strongly recommended solution is to remove the hobbyist electronics from the bike. You could cause some serious traffic accidents.